# Force on a particle from geodesic equation

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, action, geodesics

Say I had an action for a scalar field where the matter action is $$S_m=\int d^4x \sqrt{-\tilde{g}}\mathcal{L}_m(\psi,\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu})\tag{1}$$
such that matter will follow geodesics according to $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$ and
$$ \tilde{g_{\mu\nu}}\equiv A^2(\phi)g_{\mu\nu},\tag{2}$$

$$A(\phi) \approx 1+\frac{1}{2M^2}\phi^2\tag{3}.$$ I was wondering how to get the force a test particle would experience from this?

My intuition is that its related to the geodesic equation, using $\tilde{\Gamma}^\alpha_{\beta\gamma}$ instead of $\Gamma^\alpha_{\beta\gamma}$ but I'm not entirely sure.

Hopefully I'm also correct in thinking 
$$\tilde{\Gamma}^\alpha_{\beta\gamma}=\frac{1}{2}\tilde{g}^{\alpha\delta}(\tilde{g}_{\delta\beta,\gamma}+\tilde{g}_{\delta\gamma,\beta}-\tilde{g}_{\beta\gamma,\delta})\tag{4}$$

Many thanks!

Comment: Some explanations needed. What are $\psi$ and $\phi$. Are they same?

Comment: $\phi$ is a scalar field and $\psi$ is the matter field(s).